# Accessing the address of an object in a pointer handle

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I am creating a pointer class, but I can't figure out how to return the value (address of the object pointed to) of the raw pointer handled by my class. My class is like this.

```
template<typename T>
class Ptr {
public:
    Ptr(T t) :p{&t} { }
T* operator->() { return p; }
T& operator*() { return *p; }
T& operator[](int i) { return p[i]; }
private:
T* p;
};
```

If I will do:

```
int x = 42;
Ptr<int> y = x;
std::cout << y; //should print the address (y.p).
```

I absolutely don't know what operator to overload so if I use "y" in any expression it will return the address of the object pointed to, just like what a raw pointer does. What should I do?

Comment: Use `*y` to dereference the pointer.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter I don't want to dereference it. I just want to get the address of that pointer, which is y.

Comment: probably `&` operator.But that is not a good idea to access explicitly address of class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, your code has a bug. Your constructor is taking `t` by *value,* which means that `p` will store the address of the temporary `t` which will die at constructor exit (and the pointer will become dangling). You probably want this:

```
Ptr(T &t) : p{&t} {}
```

Even so, this means your pointer wrapper will be initialised by *objects* and not by *pointers,* which looks counter-intuitive. I'd change the constructor to accept a `T*`.

Second, you're asking how to get the "address **of** the raw pointer," but I assume you really want the "address **stored in** the raw pointer."

With this out of the way, let's turn to your question. There are several ways you can approach this.

- One is to give your class an implicit conversion to `T*`, like this:

  ```
  operator T* () const
  { return p; }
  ```

  That way, an implicit conversion from `Ptr<T>` to `T*` will exist and the compiler will use it wherever necessary, but that may be a bit more than you want.
- A more restricted version is to make the conversion explicit:

  ```
  explicit operator T* () const
  { return p; }
  ```

  Now you have to cast to the pointer explicitly:

  ```
  std::cout << static_cast<int*>(y);
  ```
- You can follow the pattern used by `std` smart pointers and provide a `get()` function:

  ```
  T* get() const
  { return p; }

  std::cout << y.get();
  ```
- Finally, if you only want this functionality for streaming, you can just overload `operator<<` for your class:

  ```
  template <class T, class Char, class Traits>
  std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& operator<< (std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits> &stream, const Ptr<T> &ptr)
  {
    return stream << ptr.operator->(); // or ptr.get(), if you implement it
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You should overload `operator T*()`.

Note that the pointer you're storing is a pointer to the parameter and becomes invalid as soon as the constructor returns, so dereferencing it anywhere causes your program to be undefined.

You probably want

```
Ptr(T* t) : p{t} { }
```

and

```
Ptr<int> y = &x;
```